# find different intervals for a vector of values, making number of values in each interval approximately equal

Tags: r

I have a vector, including several millions of values. Now I want to find different intervals (each as 3 different intervals, but may be 4, 5 or other different number of intervals), where the number of values in each interval should be approximately equal.

I just tried a manual way, that is I first make a hist plot, then look at how to find the interval to get what I want (or I first tried different intervals and see the number in these hypothesized intervals, if not satisfied then try different intervals combination). But, I think there should be a smart way to do the same thing. I simulate a small number of data to show what I want.

```r
v01 <- runif(2, 0, 1)
v12 <- runif(2, 1, 2)
v25 <- runif(2, 2, 5)

v <- c(v01, v12, v25)

hist(v)

length(v[v >= 0 & v <= 1])
# 2
length(v[v > 1  & v < 2])
# 2
length(v[v >= 2 & v < 5 ])
# 2
```

Then, the intervals: `(0, 1]`, `(1, 2]` and `[2, 5)` are what I want, because in these intervals, there are (approximately) equal number of values (i.e., 2 here). Please help give a hint about how to find different such intervals in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the breaks at particular quantiles of your data.  For example,

```
v01 <- runif(1000, 0, 1) 
v12 <- runif(1000, 1, 2)
v25 <- runif(1000, 2, 5)
v <- c(v01, v12, v25)
n <- 3  # Number of intervals
breaks <- quantile(v, (0:n)/n)  # These are the breakpoints.  You might
                                # want to round them to integers, based
                                # on your example
breaks

#           0%    33.33333%    66.66667%         100% 
# 0.0004285758 1.0002311588 1.9999579265 4.9946567267
```